# Reduce excessive painting when populating QTableView in batches

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, paint, qtableview

Here is an MRE:

```
import sys, traceback, time 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setWindowTitle('Latency in GUI and too much paint()')
            self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 1000, 800))
            self.table_view = SegmentsTableView(self)
            
            self.table_view.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False) 
            self.table_view.verticalHeader().setVisible(False) 
            self.setCentralWidget(self.table_view)
            
            self.worker_thread = QtCore.QThread()
            self.worker_thread.dead = False
            self.generate_row_batches_task = GenerateRowBatchesTask()
            self.generate_row_batches_task.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
            # connect signals and slots
            self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.generate_row_batches_task.run)
            self.generate_row_batches_task.stopped_signal.connect(self.worker_thread.quit)
            self.generate_row_batches_task.stopped_signal.connect(self.generate_row_batches_task.deleteLater)
            self.generate_row_batches_task.stopped_signal.connect(self.task_has_stopped)
            self.worker_thread.finished.connect(self.worker_thread.deleteLater)
            self.worker_thread.finished.connect(self.thread_has_finished)
            self.generate_row_batches_task.batch_delivered_signal.connect(self.populate_table)
            
            self.n_batch = 0 
            
            self.worker_thread.start()
            
        def populate_table(self, batch):
            # doesn't seem to help
            # self.table_view.setUpdatesEnabled(False)        
            
            row_count = self.table_view.model().rowCount()
            for n_row, row in enumerate(batch):
                n_new_row = row_count + n_row
                self.table_view.model().insertRow(n_new_row)
                self.table_view.model().setItem(n_new_row, 0, QtGui.QStandardItem(row[0]))
                self.table_view.model().setItem(n_new_row, 1, QtGui.QStandardItem(row[1]))
                self.table_view.resizeRowToContents(n_new_row)
                
            self.n_batch += 1
            print(f'self.n_batch {self.n_batch}')    

            # doesn't seem to help
            # self.table_view.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
                    
            if row_count == 0:
                print('row count 0')
                self.table_view.setColumnWidth(0, 400)
                self.table_view.setColumnWidth(1, 400)
        
        def task_has_stopped(self):
            print('task has stopped')

        def thread_has_finished(self):
            print('thread has finished')
            
class GenerateRowBatchesTask(QtCore.QObject):
    stopped_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    batch_delivered_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    
    def run(self):
        rows = [
         ['one potatoe two potatoe', 'one potatoe two potatoe'],
         ['Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque',
          'Sed ut <b>perspiciatis, unde omnis <i>iste natus</b> error sit voluptatem</i> accusantium doloremque'],
         ['Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui do lorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing velit, sed quia non numquam do eius modi tempora incididunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.',
          'Nemo enim ipsam <i>voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, <b>aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, <u>sed quia</i> consequuntur</u> magni dolores eos</b>, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui do lorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing velit, sed quia non numquam do eius modi tempora incididunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.'
          ],
         ['Ut enim ad minima veniam',
          'Ut enim ad minima veniam'],
         ['Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit',
          'Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit'],
         ['At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.',
          'At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.'
         ]]
        print('run')
        # this multiplies the list to give one with 192 rows 
        for i in range(3):
            rows += rows
        # now deliver 400 batches of these 192 rows
        # NB these time.sleep()s have been chosen to produce just a bit of annoying latency in the GUI
        for i in range(400):
            batch = []
            for n_row, row in enumerate(rows):
                batch.append(row)
                if n_row % 20 == 0:
                    time.sleep(0.000001)
            self.batch_delivered_signal.emit(batch)
            time.sleep(0.001)
        self.stopped_signal.emit()                
        
class SegmentsTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setItemDelegate(SegmentsTableViewDelegate(self))
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())
        v_header =  self.verticalHeader()
        # 
        v_header.setMinimumSectionSize(5)
        v_header.sectionHandleDoubleClicked.disconnect()
        v_header.sectionHandleDoubleClicked.connect(self.resizeRowToContents)
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.resizeRowsToContents)        
        
    def resizeRowToContents(self, row):
        super().resizeRowToContents(row)
        self.verticalHeader().resizeSection(row, self.sizeHintForRow(row))

    def resizeRowsToContents(self):
        header = self.verticalHeader()
        for row in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            hint = self.sizeHintForRow(row)
            header.resizeSection(row, hint)    
            
class SegmentsTableViewDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    class EditorDocument(QtGui.QTextDocument):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.setDocumentMargin(0)
            self.contentsChange.connect(self.contents_change)
            self.height = None
            parent.setDocument(self)
        
        def contents_change(self, position, chars_removed, chars_added):
            def resize_func():
                if self.size().height() != self.height:
                    doc_size = self.size()
                    self.parent().resize(int(doc_size.width()), int(doc_size.height()))
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, resize_func)
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.pm_index_to_editor_dict = {}
        self.paint_count = 0
    
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        class Editor(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
            def resizeEvent(self, event):
                super().resizeEvent(event)
                parent.parent().resizeRowToContents(index.row())
                
        pm_index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        if pm_index in self.pm_index_to_editor_dict:
            editor = self.pm_index_to_editor_dict[pm_index]
        else:
            editor = Editor(parent)
            editor.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            editor.setFrameShape(0)
            self.pm_index_to_editor_dict[pm_index] = editor                    
        SegmentsTableViewDelegate.EditorDocument(editor)
        return editor
    
    def destroyEditor(self, editor, index):
        super().destroyEditor(editor, index)
        pm_index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        del self.pm_index_to_editor_dict[pm_index]
        self.parent().resizeRowToContents(index.row())
        
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.paint_count += 1
        if self.paint_count % 100 == 0:
            # from this we see that it is always the visible rows (in the viewport) which are repainted
            print(f'self.paint_count {self.paint_count} index.row() {index.row()}')
        
        self.initStyleOption(option, index)
        painter.save()
        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        doc.setDocumentMargin(0)
        doc.setDefaultFont(option.font)
        doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
        doc.setHtml(option.text)
        option.text = ""
        option.widget.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter)
        painter.translate(option.rect.left(), option.rect.top())
        doc.drawContents(painter)
        painter.restore()
            
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        self.initStyleOption(option, index)
        pm_index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        if pm_index in self.pm_index_to_editor_dict:
            doc = self.pm_index_to_editor_dict[pm_index].document()
        else:
            doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
            doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
            doc.setDefaultFont(option.font)
            doc.setDocumentMargin(0)
            doc.setHtml(option.text)
        return QtCore.QSize(int(doc.idealWidth()), int(doc.size().height()))
                
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
app.setFont(default_font)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
exec_return = app.exec()
sys.exit(exec_return)
```

What I'm doing in my real app is converting documents into rows of a table. The problem is with scaling up to very large documents consisting of maybe 50,000 words and therefore many 000s of table rows.

Delivering in batches from a worker thread using a signal seems to be the way to go. I find that the amount of `time.sleep()` I then put into the worker thread has a direct relationship with the responsiveness of the GUI (best = very short but very often), and indeed omitting it completely seems to result in a crash, as though the GUI is being overwhelmed.

The problem is that, in my real application, I still find annoying latency when I'm trying to edit a cell while batches are still being delivered and added to the table. I *think* the culprit may be the item delegate's `paint` method, which is being called many 000s of times.

`paint` is happening even when I am not attempting to edit, and when the rows I can see in the viewport are completely unchanging... and yet the rows that are being painted are (as you might hope) the visible rows in the `QTableView`'s viewport.

This MRE illustrates this to some extent. I'm trying to find a way of reducing the amount of unnecessary painting going on. I'm not clear what triggers painting. In Java FX and Swing there is some mechanism of "invalidation" going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt models provide a couple of useful functions:

- [`canFetchMore(parent)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore), which says if the model can load *more* data (for a given parent);
- [`fetchMore(parent)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) tells the model to *do* load more data (but the model decides the amount of the "more");

Those functions are called by item views so that when they can *request* the model if there's more data to load whenever the user has scrolled to the end (usually, at the bottom) and eventually tell the model to do the fetching.

Considering the above, what you need to do is to implement a model that starts with a specified minimum amount of data, provides both fetching methods to load further data, and then add a timer *to the view* to request further fetching whenever it's possible, ***unless*** the current [`state()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#state) is `EditingState` *or* the model cannot fetch more data.

Since your code is too complex for an answer, I created a simpler example to explain the concept; the second columns shows when the index has been *fetched* starting from the moment the model has been created:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TestModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    totalRowCount = 1980
    currentRowCount = 25
    fetchAmount = 25
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.eTimer = QtCore.QElapsedTimer()
        self.eTimer.start()
        self.times = {
            r:0 for r in range(self.currentRowCount)
        }

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return ('Item', 'Loading time')[section]
        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.currentRowCount

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return 2

    def canFetchMore(self, parent=None):
        return self.currentRowCount < self.totalRowCount

    def fetchMore(self, parent=None):
        maxRow = min(self.totalRowCount, self.currentRowCount + self.fetchAmount)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.currentRowCount, maxRow - 1)
        t = self.eTimer.elapsed() * .001
        self.times.update({r:t for r in range(self.currentRowCount, maxRow)})
        self.currentRowCount += self.fetchAmount
        self.endInsertRows()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return 'Item at row {}'.format(index.row() + 1)
            return self.times[index.row()]

    def flags(self, index):
        return super().flags(index) | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable


class TestTable(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self._model = TestModel()
        self.setModel(self._model)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.fetchTimer = QtCore.QTimer(
            interval=1000, singleShot=True, timeout=self.fetchMore)
        self.fetchTimer.start()

    def fetchMore(self):
        if self.model().canFetchMore():
            if self.state() != self.EditingState:
                self.model().fetchMore()
            self.fetchTimer.start()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = TestTable()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

<sup>Note: the parent argument for `canFetchMore` and `fetchMore` is mandatory, just like `rowCount` and `columnCount`.</sup>

Obviously, if your model requires some time to fetch the actual data and finally insert new indexes (for instance, a remote database or network requests), you need to implement that with a further delay timer to "queue" the fetch requests.

You can create another single-shot timer in the model, and then *push* the fetching (`beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows`) whenever the model is able to do that, even using a separate thread.

<sup>As a further and unrelated suggestion, please try to put more efforts in making your examples more ***minimal***: your question is about general updating of a view with multiple items, all delegate aspects and resizing of items are completely unnecessary for that, and they just become an annoying and unnecessary distraction from what we should be focusing into.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much. I did try to make my MRE as minimal as I could, but since I knew nothing about how this "fetch more" mechanism worked I assumed I had to involve a worker thread. I also thought that the fact that it was necessary to call `resizeRowToContents` with each new row might be part of the puzzle to do with latency and repainting: hence the need to implement `paint` etc. for an HTML renderer.

Comment: @mikerodent `resizeRowToContents`, as much as any action that requires some change in the UI, automatically queues a repaint event (that's the reason for *not* calling such functions within paint or resize events, as suggested in my previous comments to your questions). In fact, if you try a basic concept of your code (without any custom delegate and no size hint change) you'd see that the repaint would be requested anyway as soon as the model is updated from the worker thread, and that's because every time the model changes its "size", the view's `updateGeometries` is called.

Comment: Even if Qt is usually well written and optimized, some functions and "event requests" are called from standard *features* of widgets, and if your subclass or implementation uses them in some way, the optimization efforts are almost nullified. I strongly suggest you to "take the leap", and begin to study the source code whenever you *really* want to know what happens *under the hood*. Even if it's written in C++, it's also usually *well* written. You can do it with https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/ which is a mirror of the official sources, with a very useful and educational interface.

Comment: Thanks... I did indeed feel like asking you (and other experts) how you actually acquire this knowledge of Qt5. I've got a couple of books on it, but even quite advanced books never cover things in enough depth once you get beyond the simple stuff. All this stuff to do with event loops, for example. I'll take a look at that mirror: I have some knowledge of C++ of course.

Comment: Understanding the event loop is usually just a matter of finding the right *metaphor* (like many other things). I sometimes consider it as a person waiting for something to happen: it could be somebody else coming in and asking something (mouse/keyboard event) or some external event like an alarm clock or life event, or even an internal wake up call ("hey, let's do something!"). Reading the source is actually one of the most important tools we have: we *directly* understand how and why things happen, which is something that books and tutorials rarely can do. It's harder, but it's worth it.

Comment: Books *are* useful, as they're an important introduction to the subject and can explain things that would require too much time to understand if you're not used to source code; also, they often provide *experience* (something that source code obviously can't) and explain you why you should or shouldn't do something, and the consequences of (not) doing it. But, as soon as you get the gist of it, you also better understand the *how* behind that *why*. If you have experience with C++, that's even better (I can read it *now*, but I never wrote a line): you'll find the link I gave you very helpful.